# Check row count and then insert value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form and i have a listbox in it to select multiple values of different dates. but requirement is one date can be booked for 2 users only once 2 users book the date then i just have to remove it from listbox.

I have created 3 tables. One table (table_dates) is just shows the dates in different rows and second table (table_users) is storing users information and third table (table_map) is mapping user with the dates.

How to write a logic to check if selected date is registered by 2 users already?

Please check my c# code below

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_users(Name,Email) OUTPUT INSERTED.userId Values (@name,@email)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    int lastId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (lastVolId > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            int counter = 0;
            string query = "";
            foreach (ListItem li in listBox.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                    {
                        // I need to write some thing here to check if selected date is registered 2 times
                        query = "INSERT INTO table_map(userId,dateId) VALUES('" + lastId + "','" + li.Value + "')";
                        cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        counter++;
                    }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //Error notification
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why did you use parameters on the first insert and then not use them on the second one? You should always use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does you table_Date has a column for a unique dateID? It is mendatory for operation u want to perform.
What u need to do is Perform a SELECT QUERY to check if it exists twice.

```
String selectStatent="SELECT * FROM table_Map WHERE dateID = @dateID";    
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand( selectStatement, connectionString);     
int rowCount = selectCommand.ExecuteScalaer();    
if(  rowCount <= 2)   
{    
  //Proceed   
}
```

Comment: Yes it has a unique id and I am storing date unique id into the mapping table. so how would i check if date id exists in mapping table twice? and if it exists less than 2 then i will run my insert query otherwise i will not do anything

Comment: Then there is no problem all you need to do is to perform a select command like above.